# How to stop pictures from bouncing aroung Word 2004

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word, word-2004

I am pasting a series of pictures into Microsoft Word 2004 for Mac, and I make them `tight` so I can fit several on the page. However, when I switch one to `tight` the rest go flying down. How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set it to be either in front of text or behind text (on the windows version it is right click, then wrap text -> front/behind, it is probably similar on a mac)

Comment: I am not using text (just pictures), but should I?

Comment: Yup. It enables free form movement of the picture (as opposed to having the pictures move when a newline is added or something.